# Basic limits as part of $\omega$-limit sets of dynamical systems

Tags: limits

I am looking at a question and solution of an $\omega$-limit set of a set $I \in X$ in dynamical systems. I have the full solution but there is something I am a little stuck on.

Here is the question:

The flow operator is defined by $S_tx=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2tx^2+1}}$

It asks to find the $\omega$-limit set of $\omega((-1,\infty))$ for the flow operator above.

The solution notes that

$S_t({0,\infty))=[0, \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2tx^2+1}}}]=[0, \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t+1/x^2}}]=[0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}}]$

and hence $S_t((-1,\infty))=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t+1}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}})$

and then the solution goes on to say that $\omega((-1,\infty))=\{0\}$

**what I am confused about, is how**

$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2tx^2+1}}= \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t+1/x^2}}$

**I would have divided by $x^2$ to get** $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1/x}{\sqrt{2t+1/x^2}}$

Am I wrong or is my lecturer wrong? I haven't done any work for a while but I thought I knew how to find limits as I learnt them years ago!

Any help on this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use that $x=\sqrt{x^2}$ (if $x$ is positive).

Comment: Im still confused could you explain further please?

Comment: Oh no it's fine sorry! That makes sense, as then divided by $x^2$ gives $\sqrt{1}=1$ as long as $x>0$ Thanks!